# newly added lines rowhandle only affects the table visually and does not save the data in the table

Tags: tabulator

The problem: I have a table that I use movableRows and rowHandle to move the rows and so far everything is fine. However, when I add values and modify it with the rowHandle, it visually changes but the saving does not occur and if I add another item, the list returns to the order without the modifications I had made.

But if I leave the items in the table, refresh the page and it loads these items already saved, this problem does not occur, only with items that were added in that section

OBS: I'm calling the tabulator through Alpine JS.